# MySQL Get same yesterday day of previous week data

Tags: mysql, datetime

Let say yesterday was Wednesday; I need to get all records for Wednesday of previous week. How to achieve this in MySQL statement condition?

Comment: You'd first deduct a week from today, forget about the hours and check Database by range for values registered on that date. It's looks a little like this WHERE date_column = '2022-05-07'. Any questions?

Comment: What do you mean by saying `all records`? Do you mean to get all wednesdays from previous week**s** or just the previous wednesday?

Comment: all record only for previous Wednesday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday would be today - 1 day. Then subtract additional 7 days:

```
select *
from t
where date_column >= current_date - interval 8 day
and   date_column <  current_date - interval 7 day
```

Comment: Sorry i've edited my question.

Comment: Dude, just subtract one more.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
 FROM Table
 where ( (datetime between date()-7 and date()) ) order by datetime DESC
```

Comment: Why did you put two `((` ,and two closing `))`, in your SQL query ? It does not improve readability, and has no function. (AFAIK)

Comment: Thanks Luuk, I prefer using parentheses with And / OR condition with where clause.